# How do you set java version in windows git bash?

Tags: windows, git-bash

How do you set the java version to use in a windows git bash? Does it work via the environment variables? Java -version gives another version in dos command prompt than in git bash...

Comment: How have you fixed this ?

Comment: I had PATH and JAVA_HOME set correctly, yet Git Bash kept on showing an older Java version. I'm running a 64 bit Win 7 and the catch was that I had an older 32 bit version on path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin'. For some reason it got picked up by Git Bash although it was not explicitly referenced from anywhere.

Comment: Same issue here. On a "normal" command line prompt, JAVA_HOME points to the jdk8. In Git Shell, if I compile an android project for example, it complains JAVA_HOME points to the jre8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't set the java version.  You are seeking the `$PATH` (bash) and the `%PATH%` (Windows/DOS/cmd.exe) environment variables.  When you run the command `java -version`, the shell searches the directories on the `$PATH` to locate the `java` program and run it with the given arguments.  If you get different results in different shells then that means you have different PATHs such that a different installation of Java is found.

Comment: Edit your $HOME/.bashrc or $HOME/.login.  See `man bash` for details on how bash handles startup configuration.

Comment: for posterity: `export PATH="/c/Program Files/Java/<jdk>/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 35):

Let's say you want to try other Java versions but you don't want to alter the Windows environment variables.

Steps:

- Go to your home folder. i.e. C:\Users\MyAccountName
- Edit the .bashrc file and add the following code below.

  ```
  #For example:
  export JAVA_HOME='/c/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_45'
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  ```
- .bashrc and .bash_profile are files created during the git-bash installation.

Comment: You can also use both statements in a shell skript (executed by git bash) if you just want to change the java version for a specific shell skript. This worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables
2. New System Variable
3. 'Variable name': PATH
4. 'Variable value': C\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin (or whatever your path is)
5. Restart Git Bash

(Windows 10)

Comment: I ended up doing the same. With multiple JDK, the first JDK found is used, i.e. switching between JDK by re-ordering path seems easier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the environment variables affect which java is used in Git Bash. But if setting the $JAVA_HOME and $PATH variables doesn't *seem* work, try this:

1. Go to the folder where Git Bash is installed (usually C:\Program Files\Git)
2. Go to usr/bin folder, i.e. C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
3. There should be a file named "java" there. Rename it to "notjava".
4. Now set the PATH variable as described in the other answers. I.e.

   export JAVA_HOME='{yourjavahome}'
5. Restart Git Bash.

This is what worked for me. I'm using Git for Windows v2.17.0.

Answer (score 1):

Go the location where you want to set java path temporarily. Run below command.
export PATH="/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.1/bin:$PATH"

User the jdk version you want in place of jdk-11.0.1